# how to find and correct plugin query performance issues

Tags: plugins, performance, debug, memory

I have recently uploaded a new site I've been working on for a while - which is working and performing very well on the localhost - there is no notable sluggishness to the load-times.

Once uploaded to the server ( dreamhost dreampress WordPress optimized VPS ) - the site is so slow as to be almost unusable - what should I test, how and with what tools?

While my question may be very specific - I'd like to know about a good general routine for debugging and fixing this type of environmental difference - and include the following data to show people what I've looked into so far.

Update --- :

The number of requests and cached hits to the database is roughly equal between the local and live site - but the main problem seems to be a very long "waiting" cycle on page loads - between 10 - 20 seconds - but how can I find out what is happening in that time - what is the site waiting for?

Update ---- :

Tested page load via [pingdom](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/) - averaging about 12 - 15 seconds to load
Tested DNS - all 6 tests passed without error
Tested Ping / TraceRoute - all clear

Plugin Data ---- :

Here is a pie chart from the godaddy P3 plugin for the localhost plugin resource usage and load time impact:

[image]

However, once uploaded ( to dreampress WordPress optimized VPS server ) the site is so sluggish and unresponsive, it's almost unusable - here is the same data from the live site:

[image]

The SabaiDiscuss Wrappers plugin goes form using 4% or resources to over 50% - the number of queries jump from 71 to 159

There are two additional plugin running on the live site - MinQueue to cache and minify scripts / sources and another debugging plugin.

Debug Bar gives me these two sets of data:

Localhost ---- :

```
PHP
5.3.5
MySQL
5.5.8
Memory Usage
35,760,984 bytes

TOTAL QUERIES:
82
TOTAL QUERY TIME:
56.2 ms
```

Development Server --- :

```
PHP
5.3.27
MySQL
5.0.67
Memory Usage
29,408,256 bytes

TOTAL QUERIES:
88
TOTAL QUERY TIME:
6,497.3 ms
```

Which seems to show the same number of queries are being run, but taking 1000 times longer to complete.

Comment: I would ask the plugin developer.

Comment: I already have - it's a premium plugin - but for $20 I've already got a lot of goodness - locally this runs like a dream, but it's hanging 15 - 20 seconds each page load on the development server..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an amazing plugin (as usual) called Query Monitor that will give you an amazing set of stats about all the queries run on a page load.

You can see how many queries are made, by which components, how long they take - pretty much everything. I wouldn't necessarily run this on a live site very much, depending on your traffic & users. Be sure to read the instructions to be sure it doesn't output to the public.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/

Comment: Excellent - I'll add that to the tool kit today and take a look.

Comment: the problem turned out to be a server misconfiguration causing a huge latency on mySQL calls - but Query Monitor is now a first-install for new projects - I fixed up lots of other small issues which had been around for a while!